# Cross Validation for longitudinal/panel data in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, cross-validation

I have some longitudinal/panel data that takes the form below (code for data entry is below the question). Observations of X and y are indexed by time and country (eg USA at time 1, USA at time 2, CAN at time 1).

```
    time x  y
USA 1    5  10
USA 2    5  12
USA 3    6  13
CAN 1    2  2
CAN 2    2  3
CAN 3    4  5
```

I'm trying to predict `y` using sklearn. For a reproducible example, we could use, say, linear regression.

In order to perform CV, I can't use `test_train_split` because then the split might, for example, put data from `time = 3` in `X_train`, and data from `time = 2` into `y_test`. This would be unhelpful, because at `time = 2`, when we would be trying to predict `y`, we would not yet really have data at `time = 3` to train on.

I'm trying to use `TimeSeriesSplit` in order to achieve CV as shown in this image:

[image]
(source: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection)

```
y = df.y
X = df.drop(['y'], 1)
print(y)
print(X)
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

X = X.to_numpy()

from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 2, max_train_size=3)
print(tscv)
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

which gives close to what I need, but not quite:

```
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
TRAIN: [1 2 3] TEST: [4 5]
```

- How can I now use `TimeSeriesSplit` indices to cross-validate a model?

I believe a complication may be that my data isn't strictly time-series: it's not only indexed by `time`, but also by `country`, hence the longitudinal/panel nature of the data.

My desired output is:

1. A series of test and train indices that allow me to perform "walk forward" CV

eg

```
TRAIN: [1] TEST: [2]
TRAIN: [1 2] TEST: [3]
```

2. An `X_train`, `x_test`, `y_test`, `y_train` that are split using the index above, based on the value of `time`, or clarity as to whether I need to do that.
3. An accuracy score of any model (eg. linear regression) cross-validated using the "walk forward" CV method.

Edit: thank you to @sabacherli for answering the first part of my question, and fixing the errors that were being thrown up.

## Code for Data Entry

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([['country','time','x','y'],
                ['USA',1, 5, 10],
                ['USA',2, 5, 12],
                ['USA',3,6, 13],
                ['CAN',1,2, 2],
                ['CAN',2,2, 3],
                ['CAN',3,4, 5]],                
               )
                
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])

df
```

Comment: How about converting your X DataFrame to a numpy object with X.to_numpy()

Comment: @sabacherli That fixed the errors! Thank you so much. I might edit the question so that I can ask for help on the next step: how to implement the times-series cross validation using the time-series split indices you just help me get, if that's okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TimeSeriesSplit` assumes that your dataset is indexed by time, meaning each row belongs to a different time step. So why not `unstack` the data such you only have time as an index and then split. After the split, you can `stack` the data shape again to get your underlying table for training.

```
data = np.array([['country','time','x','y'],
                ['USA',1, 5, 10],
                ['USA',2, 5, 12],
                ['USA',3,6, 13],
                ['CAN',1,2, 2],
                ['CAN',2,2, 3],
                ['CAN',3,4, 5]],                
               )

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])

df1 = df.reset_index().set_index(['time','index']).unstack(-1)
print(df1)
```

```
        x       y    
index CAN USA CAN USA
time                 
1       2   5   2  10
2       2   5   3  12
3       4   6   5  13
```

Now, since each row is indexed by time, you can easily split this data into groups and then after split, stack again to get your X_train X_test, etc...

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 2, max_train_size=3)

X_cols = ['time', 'index', 'x']
y_cols = ['y']

for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(df1):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = df1.iloc[train_index].stack(-1).reset_index()[X_cols].to_numpy(), df1.iloc[test_index].stack(-1).reset_index()[X_cols].to_numpy()
    y_train, y_test = df1.iloc[train_index].stack(-1).reset_index()[y_cols].to_numpy(), df1.iloc[test_index].stack(-1).reset_index()[y_cols].to_numpy()
```

```
TRAIN: [0] TEST: [1]
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2]
```

You can print the latest fold's X_train and y_train to see whats happening -

```
print('For - TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2]')
print(" ")
print("X_train:")
print(X_train)
print(" ")
print("X_test:")
print(X_test)
print(" ")
print("y_train:")
print(y_train)
print(" ")
print("y_test:")
print(y_test)
print("X_train:")
print(X_train)
print(" ")
print("X_test:")
print(X_test)
print(" ")
print("y_train:")
print(y_train)
print(" ")
print("y_test:")
print(y_test)
```

```
For - TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2]

X_train:
[['1' 'CAN' '2']
 ['1' 'USA' '5']
 ['2' 'CAN' '2']
 ['2' 'USA' '5']]
 
X_test:
[['3' 'CAN' '4']
 ['3' 'USA' '6']]
 
y_train:
[['2']
 ['10']
 ['3']
 ['12']]
 
y_test:
[['5']
 ['13']]
```

So now you can split a dataframe by time, and expand it back to the shape you need it for training.

Comment: For the next step, once I have the time-series split, could I just pass the split into say `GridSearchCV` like this: `GridSearchCV(my_pipeline, param_grid, cv = tscv.split(df1), ...)`? That's what I'm doing at the moment, and I thought I'd check with you that that makes sense. Thank you again.